# Exclude timestamps in given interval on given days of the week

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I want to do the opposite than this:

```
SELECT *
FROM cih
WHERE location IS NOT NULL
AND extract(dow FROM timestamp_client)<6
AND extract(dow FROM timestamp_client)!=0
AND extract(HOUR FROM timestamp_client)<=18
AND extract(HOUR FROM timestamp_client)>=9
```

What I want is extract the data for these cases:

```
1. 0<dow<6 and (hour<9 or hour>18)
2. dow=0 or dow=6
```

But I do not know how to write it in PostgreSQL syntax. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
AND (extract(dow  FROM timestamp_client) IN (0,6) OR 
 NOT extract(hour FROM timestamp_client) BETWEEN 9 AND 18)
```

That excludes everything on dow 1 - 5 between 09:00 and 18:59:59.999999.
Parentheses required.

There are many other ways. The best solution depends on the complete picture.

Answer (score 0):

Let's name your conditions:

```
A : 0 < dow < 6
B : hour < 9 OR hour > 18
C : dow = 0 OR dow = 6
```

Your conditions are:

```
1: A AND B    OR
2: C
```

In short:

```
A AND B OR C
```

Now, let's see [simplification rules](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-31/lectures/simplify/lecture.html), one of them is:

```
C OR (A AND B) <==> (C OR A) AND (C OR B)
```

Since `dow` can only take values from 0 to 6 we can conclude that `C <=> NOT A`.

Now, your simplified condition is:

```
(NOT A OR A) AND (NOT A OR B)
```

`(NOT A OR A)` is always true, so we can skip it.

Ufff :) now we only have `NOT A OR B`. Remember that `C <=> NOT A`? If yes, we have even simpler form: `C OR B`, which, for your original conditions is:

```
(hour < 9 OR hour > 18) OR (dow = 0 OR dow = 6)
```

Now we have only `OR` which can be simply used in SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM cih
WHERE location IS NOT NULL AND (
extract(dow FROM timestamp_client) = 0 OR
extract(dow FROM timestamp_client) = 6 OR
extract(HOUR FROM timestamp_client) < 9 OR
extract(HOUR FROM timestamp_client) > 18)
```

Don't forget the parenthesis as `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`!

This can be further simplified, exactly as @ErwinBrandstetter did ;)